# Auto indexing vs batch importer indexing. What's the difference?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I see that there are two ways of creating indexes on the node and relationship properties. One is to create the header row with columns in the format as below
Property:Type:Index on the first line of nodes.csv or rels.csv and then uncomment Auto indexing lines in batch.properties file.
Other way is, to specify which properties need to be indexed in the neo4j.propeties file. 
Yet an other way is to create indexes from cypher language. Given we have at least these 3 ways of creating indexes, which one should I use. When I do batch import of graph with indexes specified in the header, it takes awfully long time to insert the graph. Without indexes specified, it took 10 mins to insert and with took 5 hours on a 250 GB memory machine.
If I do the second way, then server startup takes forever and sometimes fail to start with "auto upgrade failed" message after some time. 
So please advice what's the best way to create indexes
Also should u create indexes for the id, label and type columns or not needed since they are auto created?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a good reason, go with the schema indexes - those based on a label and a property.

I've written a blog post on the different types of indexes, see blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/12/indexing-in-neo4j-an-overview/.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for the comment. Saw yout blog post which says schema indexes are better than auto indexes. So you say that option 2 is better? Also what is full text index and should I specify this in neo4j.propeties? Also do I need to do schema indexes for id, label and type columns or batch importer will automatically create indexes on those columns?

Comment: a full text index is a manual index with a specific configuration. You cannot configure those in neo4j.properties.

Comment: Indexes are just on properties. maybe read through the reference documentation as well.